# Google search widget has bad quality images

Tags: google, app-widgets

When i search from the google app widget, the images are low quality. How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you allowed to share your device and system software, to narrow the possibilities?

Comment: Yes, i have an lg k20 plus, but this happens on all my devices, and multiple different networks. I even tried android x86

Comment: Maybe your Internet connection is the cause of the problem..

Comment: Multiple devices, multiple networks. Including my neighbor's top tier cox internet

Comment: Is it better resolution when searching in chrome browser? Is it possible that the specific images were posted in low resolution? What happens when you open the image?

Comment: yes in chrome images have great res

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason for having a low resolution picture to begin with is so that you save on data costs. Why load 10 images in HD when you actually only need one?

So load 10 in low res and then high res for the one you want. As usual there should always be an option to chose what quality you want just like BBM which allows you the option to automatically accept HD images.

Comment: there is no option this is the googlequicsearchbox widget